# Mysql circular replication with 3 servers doesn't work

Tags: mysql, replication

I setup replication with 3 servers A, B, C.

If I add a row in server A, it is replicated to server B, If I add a row in server B it is replication in server C and if I add the row in C it is replicated in A, But the row added in server A doesn't show up in server C, I mean it doesn't circulate among replication servers.

Is there anything I missed? any configuration to force the updates to circulate among all servers?

Comment: If that happened, then you'd get a new record in b, then c, then A, then. C then... When do you break the chain. One insert in A would keep going until you ran out of disk space.

Comment: No it won't happen. The replication system knows the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To chain the replication you must set `log-slave-updates` in my.cnf

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) for more info.